# Прерывания/многопоточность python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Пишу не сложную прогу декодера(и других модулей приемо-передающего тракта до и после него) на питоне.
Ситуация следующая, есть некоторые модули которые генерирую, кодируют, модулируют и затем отдают некоторую информацию. На приемной стороне есть демодулятор и декодер с некоторым буфером конечного размера. Декодер декодирует пока что-то есть в буфере иначе ждёт. Передающий тракт должен генерировать последовательность заданной длины с определенной периодичностью, например каждый 5 секунд. Как лучше сделать это? Т.к. раньше работал с мк в голову сразу пришла идея прерывания по таймеру для выполнения некоторой задачи.
Порыл в интернетах, там все пугают gil и тем что он сильно замедлит программу. С гил я тоже не до конца понял принцип работы, он проверяет освободились ли ресурсы от прошлого потока и затем запускает следующий или проверяет наличие претендентов на ресурсы с каким-то фиксированным интервалом времени?

Comment: То как я вижу концепцию которую хочу реализовать: декодер крутится в бесконечном цикле, через фиксированные интервалы времени цикл останавливается, выполняется часть «передатчика» которая кладёт информацию в буфер, цикл с декодером продолжается

Comment: По факту из за GIL многопоточность в питоне практически бесполезна. многопоточностью в питоне решают только задачи, которые в нормальном случае должны решать асинхронностью (например через asyncio). А то что в других языках принято решать многопоточностью в питоне можно реализовать только на многопросессности. Ну это если действительно одного ядра не хватает, а если хватает, то вопрос а зачем вообще нужны потоки. А что до GIL, поток его захватил и пока не начнет выполнять ввод-вывод он его держит и никому не отдаст. поэтому и вопрос, а чем это лучше asyncio

Comment: А с "определенной периодичностью, раз в 5 секунд", какие отклонения допустимы по времени, только не говорите как в ОС реального времени на МК ... на одном процессе на питоне ничего подобного добиться все равно не удастся, даже приблизительно, если есть хоть какие требующие процессор операции

Comment: @Mike желательно как можно точнее. Мне это необходимо чтобы проверить зависимость количества ошибок декодера от скорости входных данных. Мне не особо важно будет ли останавливаться декодер в то время, когда в буфер будут поступать новые данные, важно чтобы данные поступали в фиксированные промежутки. 
А что если сделать два параллельных процесса, один будет выполнять все вычисления "передатчика" и в определенные момент времени просто класть эти данные в буфер кодера (возможно, резервируя общие ресурсы для себя на момент взаимодействия), такой вариант получится сделать достаточно точно?

Comment: @Mike или мне лучше не мучать себя и переехать на плюсы с этой задачей?

Comment: Мне кажется два процесса вполне могут обеспечить то что вам надо, если вы придумаете как между ними передать данные. Использовать видимо придется как можно более низкоуровневые примитивы разделямой памяти. буквально сырые ее регионы. Все классы, реализующие в питоне более высокоуровневые примитивы, дающие нормальные питоновские типы данных, делают это очень своеобразно, например через сокеты.

Comment: Есть неплохие вещи, вроде multiprocessing.Queue, но они то же на сокетах. Если ваша `C` реализация могла бы жить на сокетах и подходить под ваши требования, то думаю и multiprocessing вас устроит. А если нет и вы бы могли себе позволить только общие регионы памяти, то про мультироцессность в питоне то же придется забыть (если сырые примитивы не устроят)

Comment: А в чем проблема сокетов, я не сильно подкован в этом вопросе? @Mike

Comment: один раз в 5 секунд - тут и на гил то пофиг. когда надо 500раз в секунду чтото делать - тогда задумывайтесь о блокировках. а пока подойдет наивная реализация на 2х потоках.

Comment: @Danil Очень может быть, что eri прав и вы просто не заметите разницы. как бы ни делали. при условии что один поток не будет чисто на процессоре, питоновским кодом обрабатывать что то более 5 секунд подряд

Comment: Кратко опишу задачу, чтобы было понятна проблема. У меня есть последовательный декодер, который ходит по кодовому древу туда-обратно и ищет правильный путь, попутно исправляя закравшиеся ошибки. Время поиска этого пути будет зависеть от кол-ва ошибок, если их много он может долго искать нужный путь, если ошибок нет, он всегда будет выбирать правильный путь и идти вперед. Декодер имеет ограниченное количество "шагов назад" для поиска места где он ошибся. Количество этих шагов определяется степенью заполненности буфера, откуда он берет данные (куда данные кладет передатчик)
@eri

Comment: Пример: если буфер заполнен на 70% то декодер может сделать только 5 шагов назад, но потом будет вынужден идти вперед, пусть даже по не верному пути. Если буфер заполнен на 10 процентов, то он может позволить себе больше и будет искать путь даже 15 шагов назад (цифры примерны). Поэтому я буду менять условные 5 секунд поступления данных, чтобы буфер заполнялся и декодер допускал ошибки, так я хочу построить кривые зависимостей количества ошибок декодера от скорости передачи данных @Mike

Comment: Важность в том, что декодер должен быть остановлен во время наступления этого периода (эти 5 секунд), данные положены в буфер и декодер продолжит свои скитания по кодовому древу. Возможно ли такое реализовать с потоками?

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит заниматься блокировками и прерываниями пока без них не обойтись. GIL страшен в нагруженных приложениях и лишь не дает утилизировать больше одного ядра. Если Ваша программа кушает меньше 80% процентов времени ядра процессора - борьба с GIL не даст ничего.

Для текущей задачи достаточно реализации через timer  https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects для генерации и блокирующей очереди https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get для приёма.

Системные прерывания делаются через https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGALRM, встречал этот метод в крупных проектах - пришлось выпиливать его оттуда)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю что можно с этим сделать. Реализацию с SIGALRM я находил, но на сколько я понял, на винде данный сигнал отсутствует.